Need help with 3 dimmer switches controlling a light wired in what appear to be parallel
DIYer here, not an electrician. Fairly handy with circuits (so I thought), and I've never seen this before.
Our foyer chandelier in our 34 year old home is controlled by 3 separate dimmer switches. They are model EN600M Enhance (I cannot find anything on the internet about these besides the fact that these appear to have been manufactured by Prescolite. I cannot find a wiring diagram). Each dimmer has a black, red and purple wire coming out of it - no wire nuts.
We recently replaced our chandelier with a LED one, and these dimmers do not work. So i'm attempting to replace them.
Dimmer 1:

Black wire connecting to live (verified with voltage tester)
Red wire connecting to a brown wire
Purple wire connecting to a brown wire

Dimmer 2:

Black wire connecting to live (verified with voltage tester)
Red wire connecting to two brown wires
Purple wire connecting to two brown wires

Dimmer 3:

Black wire connecting to live (verified with voltage tester)
Red wire connecting to a black wire
Purple wire connecting to a green wire

This flies in the face of every dimmer wiring diagram i have ever seen. This seems to me like all three dimmer switches are wired in parallel, but if so, do you even need traveler wires? I would assume that the brown wires in the first two dimmers are travelers, but then I don't understand the wiring of the 3rd switch. Seems to me like if they were wired in parallel, the 3rd wire on the switches isn't doing anything?
For context, I was looking to replace with a Lutron caseta PD-5NE + 2 pico remotes. Also, since the chandelier has already been replaced, I'm unable to verify the original behavior of the switches (any of 3 on for on, all 3 off for off)
Any help here would be most appreciated

it sounds like you have two 3 way and one 4 way

@Traveler: I wasn't aware they made 3-way/4-way dimmers; the only solution I knew for that was smart switches communicating with each other.

@keshlam Prescolite Controls Enhance Series Linear 3-Way Slide Dimmer # EN600-3P-I

Can you elaborate on how the chandelier interacted with those three dimmers? For example, could you switch the lights on at position 1, change the intensity at position 2 and then switch them off at position 3? Or would you have to ensure all three switches were in the OFF position for the lights to go off?
